# Syntax of constructor in an explicit specialization

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class D{/* */};
class P{/* */};
class U{/* */};

// Generic version not defined
template <typename R>
class UEB;

// Specialization
template <>
class UEB<D> {
public:
    explicit UEB(D& /* r */)
    {}
};

// Specialization
template <>
class UEB<P> {
public:
    explicit UEB(P& /* r */)
    {}
};

template <>
class UEB<U> {
public:
    explicit UEB(U& /* r */)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    P p;
    U u;

    UEB<D>   ud(d);
    UEB<P>   up(p);
    UEB<U>   uu(u);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles fine with both GCC 7, 8 and clang with `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra`.
cppcheck however complains that `UEB<P>` and `UEB<U>` do not have constructors.

So I changed `explicit UEB(U& /* r */)` to `explicit UEB<U>(U& /* r */)` (and P similarly) and not only does it still compile, cppcheck stopped complaining.

My question is: why does this work? Is the template parameter optional when declaring the constructor of an explicitly specialized template class?

Comment: cppcheck is far from perfect.

Comment: I was going to post an answer claiming that constructors, having no name, have special declaration rules, allowing both the injected class name *and* the class template *name<args-list>* forms; now, I'm sure this holds true for primary class templates and partial specializations (as by **[class.ctor]** and **[temp.dep.type]**), but I cannot find anything about *explicit* specializations for which only the injected class name seems allowed ... so, are both gcc and clang wrong to accept the workaround code, or am I missing something ?

Comment: If both GCC and clang agree, I'm inclined to believe them :)

Comment: @bullet sadly, sometimes gcc and clangs do agree on bugs too, when dealing with corner cases, or rarely used syntax, or on the interpretation of unclear standard wording (as in this case). Indeed, the wording about template injected class names seems to have changed from c++11 to c++14 (due to defect reports) ...